# most of the time get connection reset by peer exception in my android app

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

When I run the following code, I get a "connection reset by peer" exception in most instances.

```
        String rest = System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        String uri = WEB_LOG_IN + "?user_username=" + user_email
                + "&user_password=" + user_pass + "&user_mac=" + user_mac;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
        HttpResponse response;

        String s;
        try {
            response = client.execute(httppost);
            s = new String(EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()),
                    "UTF-8");

            // read json

            if (s.length() > 2)
                return readlogin_info(s);
            else
                return false;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }
```

`String rest = System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");`
returns null which means no "http.keepAlive" property.

I tried using httpurlconnection, but that also didn't work.

I am so confused because I think the code works without issue for some ISPs.

Comment: my investigations!

    String pro = System.getProperty("http.keepAlive");
 String rest = System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
sometimes return null when the device is connected to Internet via (Mikrotik RB951Ui Router)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my investigation the exception caused by Mikrotik Router latency! (Maybe! Please correct me if I am wrong!)
so I put the execute section in a while until it can get the answer from server, after multiple execution I see after 2 times of trying to connect it successfully get the answer.

```
int count = 0;
while (s == null) {
            count++;
            try {
                response = client.execute(httpGet);
                s = new String(
                        EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()),
                        "UTF-8");
                // read json
                if (s.length() > 2)
                {
                    return readlogin_info(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```